# Как сделать REST запрос с куками стандартными инструметами java

Tags: java

Вот запрос.

```
package reindex2;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie;


public class MyClass{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {


        URL url2 = new URL("http://n7701-sys253:8080/plugins/servlet/restbrowser#/resource/api-2-projectcategory/login.cgi?Name=kononov&Password=P@ssw0rd ");
//      URL url2 = new URL("http://n7701-sys253:8080/plugins/servlet/restbrowser#/resource/api-2-projectcategory/");
        HttpURLConnection con2 = (HttpURLConnection)url2.openConnection();

//      NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie("kononov", "P@ssw0rd");

        con2.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        con2.setReadTimeout(5000);
        con2.setDoInput(true);
        con2.setRequestMethod("GET");
//      con2.setRequestMethod(cookie);
        con2.connect();
        if(con2.getResponseCode() >= 200 && con2.getResponseCode() < 300) {
            try ( Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(con2.getInputStream(), "utf-8");
                    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(reader);)
            {
                String line = "";
                while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Код: " + con2.getResponseCode());}
        if (con2 != null)
            con2.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Вот ответ.

```
fieldset class="hidden parameters">
    <input type="hidden" title="loggedInUser" value="">
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxTimeout" value="Вызов сервера JIRA не был завершен в течение тайм-аута.  Мы не уверены в результате этой операции.">
    <input type="hidden" title="JiraVersion" value="7.7.1" />
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxUnauthorised" value="Вы не авторизованы для выполнения этой операции. Пожалуйста, войдите.">
    <input type="hidden" title="baseURL" value="http://n7701-sys253:8080" />
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxCommsError" value="Невозможно связаться с сервером JIRA. Это может быть временный сбой или сервер недоступен. ">
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxServerError" value="Сервер JIRA доступен, но вернул сообщение об ошибке. Мы не уверены в результате этой операции.">
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxErrorCloseDialog" value="Закройте это диалоговое окно и нажмите обновление в браузере">
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxErrorDialogHeading" value="Разрыв связи">

    <input type="hidden" title="dirtyMessage" value="Вы ввели новую информацию на этой странице. Если вы покинете страницу, предварительно не сохранив изменения, они будут потеряны.">
    <input type="hidden" title="dirtyDialogMessage" value="Вы ввели в это окно новые данные. Если вы уйдете из этого окна, не сохранив данные, все изменения будут потеряны. Чтобы вернуться к окну, нажмите «отменить».">
    <input type="hidden" title="keyType" value="Тип">
    <input type="hidden" title="keyThen" value="затем">
    <input type="hidden" title="dblClickToExpand" value="Двойное нажатие для раскрытия">
    <input type="hidden" title="actions" value="Действия">
    <input type="hidden" title="removeItem" value="Удалить">
    <input type="hidden" title="workflow" value="Бизнес-процесс">
    <input type="hidden" title="labelNew" value="Новая метка">
    <input type="hidden" title="issueActionsHint" value="Начните набирать для поиска доступных операций или нажмите вниз, чтобы увидеть все">
    <input type="hidden" title="closelink" value="Закрыть">
    <input type="hidden" title="dotOperations" value="Действия">
    <input type="hidden" title="dotLoading" value="Загрузка...">
    <input type="hidden" title="frotherSuggestions" value="Предложения">
    <input type="hidden" title="frotherNomatches" value="Нет совпадений">
    <input type="hidden" title="multiselectVersionsError" value="{0} не является корректной версией.">
    <input type="hidden" title="multiselectComponentsError" value="{0} - некорректный компонент.">
    <input type="hidden" title="multiselectGenericError" value="Некорректное значение {0}.">
</fieldset>

            </footer>

    </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/s/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e-CDN/fba21d/77002/be09033ea7858348cd8d5cdeb793189a/1.0/_/download/batch/jira.webresources:bigpipe-js/jira.webresources:bigpipe-js.js" data-wrm-key="jira.webresources:bigpipe-js" data-wrm-batch-type="resource" data-initially-rendered></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/s/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e-CDN/fba21d/77002/be09033ea7858348cd8d5cdeb793189a/1.0/_/download/batch/jira.webresources:bigpipe-init/jira.webresources:bigpipe-init.js" data-wrm-key="jira.webresources:bigpipe-init" data-wrm-batch-type="resource" data-initially-rendered></script>

<form id="jira_request_timing_info" class="dont-default-focus" >
    <fieldset class="parameters hidden">
        <input type="hidden" title="jira.request.start.millis" value="1519133898917" />
        <input type="hidden" title="jira.request.server.time" value="62" />
        <input type="hidden" title="jira.request.id" value="998x2648x1" />
        <input type="hidden" title="jira.session.expiry.time" value="-" />
        <input type="hidden" title="jira.session.expiry.in.mins" value="-" />
        <input id="jiraConcurrentRequests" type="hidden" name="jira.request.concurrent.requests" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" title="db.conns.time.in.ms" value="2" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
<!--
                     REQUEST ID : 998x2648x1
              REQUEST TIMESTAMP : [20/Feb/2018:16:38:18 +0300]
                   REQUEST TIME : 0,0620
                     ASESSIONID : -
            CONCURRENT REQUESTS : 1

                          db.conns : OpSnapshot{name='db.conns', invocationCount=4, elapsedTotal=2181043, elapsedMin=275617, elapsedMax=906635, resultSetSize=0, cpuTotal=0, cpuMin=0, cpuMax=0}
-->
  </body>
  </html>
```

Почему не выходит стандартными средствами   получить GET запрос нажатия кнопки "send" ??  И какими инструментами воспользоваться лучше всего для создания REST запросов ( библиотека jersy оказалась не очень, подумываю об Apach и о Фреймворке Spring)